# #footer background solid color not working over container

Tags: html, css

http://preview.goodinkproductions.com/CG8F13

I've managed to get the footer to span the site (unlike body which is inside a container and AOK). But, I can't get the footer background to be solid. It appears I have a band of solid color below, but the footer content is not in that "space". All I want is a solid span footer with content in it!

CSS
    /* Footer
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
#footer {
width: 100%; 
background-color:#FF8800;
}
#footer-content{
width: 950px;  
height: 80px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#footer p {
color: #878787;
font-size: 12px;
}

#footer blockquote {font-size:11px; color:#999;}

#footer a {
color: #a59b8c;
}

#footer a:hover {
color: #cab99f;
}

#footer span {
vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer h2 {
font-size: 15px;
margin: 0 0 2px;
padding: .3em 0;
line-height: 1.5;
font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
color: #ebb058;
}

.wsite-footer {  /* make sure enough space between element footer and attribution */
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        {logo}
        {menu}
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                {phone:text}
                                {social}
                                {search}
                            
                        
                    
                
            
            
        
        
            
        
        
            {content}

```
</div>

</div>
<div style='padding: 20px; width:100%; text-align:center;'>{footer}</div>
</body>
<div id="footer">

   <div id="footer-content">

   </div>

</div>
</html>
```

END

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what's going on here, but you need your footer div's inside the body tag.

```
</div>

</div>
<div style='padding: 20px; width:100%; text-align:center;'>{footer}</div>
<div id="footer">

   <div id="footer-content">

   </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The footer appears to be there, with a background of #F8F8F8
There is no text in the footer in youc code...